# Multiple statuses shown in the application history

Tags: formsflow.ai, formsflow

when i check the application status history tab of New Business License application ,i got confused by the same statuses multiple times. When clicking the form only we came to know who returned/approved the form? Is there any way for the user to know from the history tab itself without clicking on the form
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no other option as of formsflow.ai v4.0.4 to show what changes are modified in case of monitoring Application History.

It depends totally upon the workflow you design, how the applicationStatus changes across each stage of workflow. So if you are confused by multiple status happening at same time, you can redesign the workflow in such a way.

[image]